# $G$ is a $p$-group $\implies $ $G$ has a normal subgroup of $p^k \ \forall k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, p-groups

I am a beginner to $p$-groups, so please help me with the following qustion:

> If $|G|=p^n$, where $p$ is prime, and $0\le k\le n$, then $G$ contains a normal subgroup of order $p^k$.

My work:

I have just been able to prove that

> $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $p$.

Since $G$ is a $p$ group, its center $Z(G)\ne \{e\}$ $\therefore$ $Z(G)$ is $p$-subgroup of $G$ .By Cauchy's lemma, there is an element $a\in Z(G)$ such that $|a|=p$.Then $N=\langle a\rangle$ is a subgroup of order $p$.Moreover since every subgroup of $Z(G)$ is normal in $G$, $\therefore$ $N\triangleleft G$.

Now I dont know how to proceed. Maybe induction will help? Or is there some better way?

Comment: Induction is indeed a good choice: Take the quotient by the subgroup of order $p$ and repeat the argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** If you know that $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ of order $p^k$, then 
$G/N$ is a $p$ group, and hence has a normal subgroup of order $p$.

Deduce that $G$ has a normal subgroup of order $p^{k+1}$.

Comment: I more or less get it. But can you please tell me what the normal subgroup in $G/N$ look like?

Comment: @Qwerty Any group in $G/N$ has the form $H/N$ for some subgroup $H$ of $G$. Show that if $H/N$ is normal in $G/N$ then $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Let $H/N$ be a normal subgroup of $G/N$. Then for any element $hN$ in $H/N$ and $gN$ in $G/N$, we have $(gN)(hN)(g^{-1}N) \in  H/N$; i.e. $(ghg^{-1})N \in H/N$; implying that $ghg^{-1}\in H$, for any $g \in G, h \in H$; so $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.         Is this correct?

Comment: @Qwerty Yes. ..

Answer (score 1):

Recall the [fourth isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)):  the subgroups of a quotient correspond to subgroups of the big group and moreover the image of a subgroup containing the kernel is normal in the quotient iff the subgroup itself was normal in the original group. Now if you have a normal subgroup of order $p^k$, $N$, consider $G/N$ having a normal subgroup of order $p$ (which you know exists by what you've already done). Then you may lift that subgroup to a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p^{k+1}$ in $G$. This completes the induction.

Comment: Why are we assuming there is normal subgroup of order $p^k$? This is part of what we have to prove.

Comment: This is the inductive hypothesis, it's different from affirming the consequent

Comment: The inductive hypothesis would say: Suppose for $p$-groups of order $p^k$ where $k<n$, there exists normal subgroups of order $p^i$ for $0\le i \le k$.

Comment: That's just not true. It's abbreviated from the format you learn in high school, but that's a stylistic point only. The argument is valid induction: there's a base case and an arbitrary case implies truth for its successor which is what induction is.

Comment: I didn't go to high school.

Comment: I meant that as the linguistic "impersonal you," the comment wasn't meant to imply anything about your particular life experiences